# How to create chat functionality in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to develop 1 chat functionality in my ASP.NET website, I have 1 Registered_User.aspx page and here in this page I want to show all the registered users with online and offline mode, after that when I select the online user for chat one message should be delivered to that user in the form of Accept/Decline and if user accept the chat then chat will be start otherwise chat will be decline.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. but, you can find dozens of chat app examples if you google signalR chat app.

Comment: You should approach this like you would eat an elephant.  One bite (byte, haha) at a time.  This is way to broad and the methods to accomplish this are almost endless.

Comment: ok so pls tell me how I send accept/decline message to the user

Answer (score 1):

You can implement everything you want just by using [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) which is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time.

You'll find a tutorial for [Getting Started with SignalR 2](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

For your purpose you can establish a temporal connection perhaps by notification then establish the persistent one.